# Size Method of a Vector resulting in a "Cannot find Symbol" Error

Tags: java-5

I'm having some issues with the following code, which uses a vector to store    print and calculate the average of a list of numbers, by the user. The issue I'm having is a Cannot find symbol error on line 9 of my script, referring to the size method that returns in the compiler. I've tried fixing it multiple times, unfortunately with no success! I'm very new to Java and any help will be appreciated so I can continue to finish the coding exercise! Please find my code below and thanks in advance:[Snippet of the error on the terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeQGi.png) [Script, Using a while loop to add elements to the vector,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q57v4.png)

Comment: Please copy your code and the error to your question (both are text); it is not very useful to take a picture of it!

Comment: Okay thanks! First time poster, will ensure to do this in the future.

Comment: Don't wait for the future, you can edit your question even if it already has an accepted answer. By updating your question in order to improve it, it will be more useful for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MyVector.size()` instead od `MyVector.size`.

Consider using an IDE, built-in checker will indicate an error and suggest solutions, it is much easier for a beginner that way.

BTW coding convention is to start variable names by lowercase letter.